# how slow are modelsim free licences?

Tags: fpga, asic, modelsim

I know in free licenses of modelsim / questa simulations run slower than the full version.

But how slow?  will it be 2x 3x 10x faster in the paid version?

what about actel/microsemi free version ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to test the license against a full version.
for very long test , the difference was quite big.

Full version simulation was a lot faster than the free licence of actel.

Comment: Alright, a quite big difference. Nice.

Answer (score 5):

ModelSim PE Student Edition limits the user to 10,000 lines of executable code. The performance of your code up to this capacity is 30% that of the full version (the full version is 3.3x faster). The student edition can still run code past the 10,000 line capacity, but it slows the performance down dramatically to 1% of the full version (the full version is 100x faster after this point).

I got this info from the 'Performance' section of Mentor's ModelSim PE Student Edition webpage:

https://www.mentor.com/company/higher_ed/modelsim-student-edition

Comment: what about actel/microsemi free version ?

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn't take a hit to performance, but it is missing features and only gives you a license for 60 days. @CristianMardones